# Is there solution to run this fuction that make say 'Hello' in complier in Dart language

Tags: dart

This is the Dart code I made to practice functions:

```dart
String sayHello(String name,int age,String country){
    print("Hello im $name , $age year old, come from $country");
 }

void main()
{
  sayHello('king',22,'us');
}
```

And the error I am getting is:

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
Info: Compiling with sound null safety
lib/main.dart:1:9:
Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'String' doesn't allow null.
 String sayHello(String name,int age,String country){
        ^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

I referenced lots of function grammar about Dart but it didn't work.

My compiler was DartPad. Can I know where is the wrong grammar in my code?

Comment: offtopic: wondering why is this in the js section when is not even tagged

Comment: You declared the return type of `sayHello` to be `String`, but you aren't returning anything. Either change the function to return a `String`, or change the return type to `void` to indicate that the function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

In Dart, this error message indicates that the function may return without a value, even though you declared the function to return a `String` value.

Just change the return type to `void`

```
void sayHello(String name,int age,String country){
  print("Hello im $name , $age year old, come from $country");
}
```